# Why it doesnt paint the pic Jpanel

Tags: java, jframe

I wanna paint a pic on the Frame but it doesnt work and i cant find my mistake pls help

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class b1 extends JPanel {

    Image img;

    public b1() {
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon u = new ImageIcon("C:/Benutzer/Julius/eclipse-workspace/JumpnRun/rsc/b1.jpg");
        img = u.getImage();


    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D f2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        f2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, override paintComponent and not paint as you did. Second, you sure you loading correctly? And is your JPanel inside a JFrame?

Comment: thanks but how do i have to paint it

Comment: Override paintComponent not paint()